# Graphql GQL cannot parse Ruby symbols or hashrockets

Tags: ruby, graphql

I have the following method that parses the mutation into a GraphqL-readable format using `GQL`

```
def query(attributes:)
    <<~GQL
      mutation {
        createBook(
          attributes: #{attributes}
        ) {
          id
          title
          publicationDate
          genre
        }
      }
    GQL
  end
```

I then send a post request to the `/graphql` endpoint while passing what the `query` returns as params. As follows

```
post '/graphql', params: { query: query(attributes: attributes) }
```

When I hit the endpoint, I get the following error

```
{"errors"=>[{"message"=>"Parse error on \":\" (COLON) }]}
```

I later realised that `GQL` cannot parse Ruby symbols , i.e `:first_name`. So I tried to convert the `attributes` hash keys into strings with `attributes.stringify`, but seems `GQL` doesn't also recognise Ruby hashrockets, so it threw the error

```
{"errors"=>[{"message"=>"Parse error on \"first_name\" (STRING) }]}
```

Is there a way to make `GraphQL` to parse Ruby symbols and/or hashrockets?

Comment: Understand that `<<~GQL` is the start of a Ruby [heredoc](https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/multiline-strings-ruby-2-3-0-the-squiggly-heredoc) string. The letters `GQL` in your code could be anything—say, `<<~FOO` or `<<~RUTO`—as long as the same letters came at the end. To debug this, the first step is to print out that string and see if it's a valid GraphQL query. I suspect you'll find that it's not.

Comment: The right way to fix this depends on which GraphQL library you're using, but regardless I'm willing to bet string interpolation (`#{...}`) is *not* the correct way to insert variables into a query. See, for example, the docs for [variables in graphql-ruby](https://graphql-ruby.org/queries/executing_queries#variables).

Comment: @JordanRunning I guess you are right. Because I have inserted the variables directly, i.e `firstName: "Ava"`, and it worked. Let me follow the link you've shared to figure out the right way to pass variables. Thanks!